# Storing Data in AngularJS on Mobile Devices

Tags: mobile, angularjs, storage

I'm currently working on a Mobile WebApp built with AngularJS. The basic functionality is similar to a simple ToDo's app: Create a list of items (with ng-repeat) and mark those items as checked or delete them from the list. Checked items are being pushed into a seperate ng-repeat controller.

My current problem is: If you reload the page or close the app, the list contents are gone. I have to be able to store the data of my ng-repeat controllers to localStorage, IndexedDB, WebSQL, Cookies or whatever solution is the most elegant on mobile devices.

I know there are several solutions out there: There's the $cookies / $cookieStore module of the Angular API, there's a solution based on prestistence.js and so on. But I couldn't figure out wich solution is the best for mobile, cross device. I don't want to restrict the app to certain plattform, though I'm primary aiming at Firefox OS atm.

Thanks for any form of advice!

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **localStorage**. The API is simple and [widely supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to store your data in the cloud I recommend using [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) in conjunction with [Angularfire](http://angularfire.com/). It will get you up and running in a matter of minutes.

First you include Firebase and AngularFire:

```
<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="angularFire.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you declare firebase as a dependency for your angular app:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['firebase']);
```

Now all you need to do is bind a Firebase URL to a model in your controller:

```
myapp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'angularFire',
  function MyCtrl($scope, angularFire) {
    var url = 'https://MyFirebaseURL.firebaseio.com/foo';
    $scope.foo = angularFire(url, $scope, 'foo');
  }
]);
```